# Typescript module augmentation with modules in multiple files

Tags: typescript

I've successfully used typescript "module augmentation" in the past as a temporary workaround when the type declarations from 
[DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) lagged behind the underlying javascript library. The type definitions were always contained in a single file, however, and a new version of a particular public library I'm using has broken the definitions into multiple modules with re-exporting, etc.

In the past this would have worked, but now it doesn't:

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';
declare module 'sequelize' {
  interface HasManyOptions {
    sourceKey?: string;
  }
```

So how can I add add **sourceKey** to the **HasManyOptions** interface with the file structure below? I've tried messing with the name of the imported module and nesting module declarations, but no love. I'm stumped.

---

*index.d.ts*

```
export * from './lib/sequelize'
```

*./lib/sequelize.d.ts*

```
export * from './associations/index'
```

*./lib/associations/index.d.ts*

```
export * from './has-many'
```

*./lib/associations/has-many.d.ts*

```
export interface HasManyOptions extends ManyToManyOptions {
    keyType?: DataType
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have a more complete repro? Sequelize's types look like they use a single-file structure. Module extensions in TS are notoriously tricky, and can be hard to debug without a specific repro case.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry all for failing to mention I'm using sequelize v5 beta (see below for install instructions). And I don't get a special error msg; it's just clear that my override is not working: `error TS2345: Argument of type '{ as: string; foreignKey: string; sourceKey: string; onDelete: string; onUpdate: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HasManyOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sourceKey' does not exist in type 'HasManyOptions'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working on my machine:

sequelize.d.ts

```
import 'sequelize';

declare module 'sequelize' {
    interface ManyToManyOptions {
        sourceKey?: string;
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
import { ManyToManyOptions, AssociationOptions } from 'sequelize';

const options: AssociationOptions = {};

const optionsToo: ManyToManyOptions = {
    sourceKey: 'foo',
};
```

https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-module-augmentation-sequelize

Edit: This is the fix that worked for BillyB.

> To recap for future readers, a 2 part solution to my problem: In these multi-file situations with re-exported declarations the module augmention needed to be in a separate file for some reason; this was not the case in a single typings file. Second, if you are augmenting interfaces that extend other interfaces, you must repeat the extends portion of the declaration; again this was not necessary with a single typing file.

Comment: Hiya Shaun and thanks for that, but you're using sequelize v4, which has all the typings in one file. My bad for not mentioning I was working with v5; that's the new version I was talking about. If you do `npm install sequelize@next` and `npm install types/sequelize#c628e47acd0cb073b69d06b38ff3fd3ce3f47dbc` (no @ in front of types) you'll see what I mean.

Comment: It still works on my machine when I upgrade. I updated the demo on GitHub.

Comment: Huh. I'll go investigate. And thanks for your time, bro.

Comment: Part of the mystery is solved, but it's still not working.

My sequelize v5 toy exploration project was trying to use new property in the same file as the declare module stmt. Who knew? I moved the declare module to a separate file as I had done previously and as you did, and I can repro your working example. 

BUT it's **replacing** `ManyToManyOptions` instead of causing "declaration merging"; inherited properties are not being found. This fails, but it should work:

    `const optionsToo: Sequelize.ManyToManyOptions = {
        sourceKey: 'foo',
        foreignKey: 'bar'
    };`

Comment: Ha! Got it. I added `extends AssociationOptions` and properties  such as `foreignKey` that are inherited from parent interfaces are recognized by tsc. Apparently tsc loses track of inheritance in this multi-file scenario; I didn't need to do this in sequelize v4 when everything was in one file

Comment: To recap for future readers, a 2 part solution to my problem: In these multi-file situations with re-exported declarations the module augmention needed to be in a separate file for some reason; this was not the case in a single typings file. Second, if you are augmenting interfaces that extend other interfaces, you must repeat the `extends` portion of the declaration; again this was not necessary with a single typing file

Comment: Giving you credit for the answer, Shaun. thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad it worked out for you and I added your comment to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the repro case @BillyB. You want this:

```
import { ManyToManyOptions, DataType } from 'sequelize'

declare module 'sequelize' {
  interface HasManyOptions extends ManyToManyOptions {
    /**
     * A string or a data type to represent the identifier in the table
     */
    keyType?: DataType
    sourceKey?: string
  }
}
```

Module augmentations aren't super well documented. Here's how this works:

1. You `declare module 'sequelize'`, telling TS that you're declaring the `sequelize` module. The way name merging works in TS, TS will merge all modules with the exact path `'sequelize'` into one module.
2. The way interface merging works in TS, your interfaces have to not only have the same name, but their *entire declarations* has to be identical (this includes `extends` clauses and type parameters). So we have to copy `keyType` over from the source declaration, which is a little gross.

I would file a bug in TypeScript's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) for this. It's surprising that TSC didn't error when you tried to declare an interface with the same exact name as an existing name as an augmentation (shadowing the original name). TSC should either throw an exception that your module exports two unrelated interfaces with the same name, or TS should not take `extends` clauses into account when performing interface merging (at least in the specific case of module augmentations).

Comment: Good point @bcherny, I will post an issue. Succinctly put, too. thx.